# Performing many means in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, interpolation, mean

Good Morning,
I am implimenting a Cressman filter for doing distance weighted averages in Numpy.. I use a Ball Tree implimentation (thanks to Jake VanderPlas) to return a list of locatations for each point in a request array.. the query array (q) is shape [n,3] and at each point has the x,y,z at point I want to do a weighted average of points stored in the tree.. the code wrapped around the tree returns points within a certain distance so I get an arrays of variable length arrays..
I use a where to find non-empty entries (ie positions where there were at least some points within the radius of influence) creating the isgood array...

I then loop over all query points to return the weighted average of the values self.z (note that this can either be dims=1 or dims=2 to allow multiple co-gridding)

so the thing that complilcates using map or other quicker methods is the nonuniformity of the lengths of the arrays within self.distances and self.locations... I am still fairly green to numpy/python but I can not think of a way to do this array wise (ie not reverting to loops)

```
self.locations, self.distances = self.tree.query_radius( q, r, return_distance=True)
t2=time()
if debug: print "Removing voids"
isgood=np.where( np.array([len(x) for x in self.locations])!=0)[0]
interpol = np.zeros( (len(self.locations),) + np.shape(self.z[0]) )
interpol.fill(np.nan)
for dist, ix, posn, roi in zip(self.distances[isgood], self.locations[isgood], isgood, r[isgood]):
    interpol[isgood[jinterpol]] = np.average(self.z[ix], weights=(roi**2-dist**2) / (roi**2 + dist**2), axis=0)
    jinterpol += 1
```

so... Any hints of how to speed up the loop?..

For a typical mapping as appied to mapping weather radar data from a range,azimuth,elevation grid to a cartesian grid where I have 240x240x34 points and 4 variables takes 99s to query the tree (written by Jake in C and cython.. this is the hard step as you need to search the data!) and 100 seconds to do the calculation... which in my opinon is slow?? where is my overhead? is np.mean efficient or as it is called  millions of times is there a speedup to be gained here? would I gain by using float32 rather than the default64... or even scaling to ints (which would be very hard to avoid wrap around in the weighting... any hints gratefully recieved!

Comment: Did you tried to run profiler on your code? Try precalculating roi**2 and dist**2 outside the loop, and using multiplication (r[isgood]*r[isgood]) instead of **. Use np.empty instead of np.zeros.

Comment: just simple timing tests with time.time() and timeit...

Answer (score 0):

You can find a discussion about the relative merits of the Cressman scheme vs using a Gaussian weight function at:

http://www.flame.org/~cdoswell/publications/radar_oa_00.pdf

The key is to match the smoothing parameter to the data (I recommend using a value close to the average spacing between data points).  Once you know the smoothing parameter, you can set an "influence radius" equal to the radius where the weight function falls to 0.01 (or whatever).

How important is speed?  If you wish, rather than calling an exponential function to determine the weight, you can make up a discrete table of weights for some fixed number of radius increments, which speeds up the calculation considerably.  Ideally, you should have data outside the grid boundaries that can be used in the mapping of the values surrounding the gridpoints (even on the boundary points of the grid).  Note this is NOT a true interpolation scheme - it won't return the observed values at the data points exactly.  Like the Cressman scheme, it's a low-pass filer.

Comment: Yep.. I have referenced your OBAN (DWA vrs linear, ie Vaghan and Mohr) paper :) ... changing to Barnes is a matter of changing the functional form of weights...  The point of writing this code is the inflexibility of REORDER... In the end I want to use this with a network of calibrated radars... this will work with an arbitary scatter of points and an arbitary set of query points.. for example fetching columns above a site is very quick and easy...